# Debugger running code that was previously in the script but has been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having errors with import. When I delete the code and re run the script, the terminal is still throwing errors from code that was previously in the script, but no longer is.

PS. I have already tried Clear Editor History and resetting VSCode.

Example: (current code)

```
from module import module
```

Error (from current code)

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'module3' from partially initialized module 'module3'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have save the file after your changes? Are you sure you are editing and running the same script?

Comment: Yes, I keep re opening the program, deleting the pycache folders, but I keep getting the same error. Thanks for commenting.